# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() on some devices

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progressdialog, runnable

I know there are already a lot of questions like this but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. The app crashes without anything shown. Also, the error doesn't occur on my device or emulator. Just on some devices (say 30-40%?).

Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

Gebruiker gebruiker = new Gebruiker();
private DatabaseHelper db;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
    if(isOnline()){
        downloadData();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Deze app vereist een actieve verbinding met het internet!")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }       
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public void downloadData() {
    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
            "Controleren op bestaande gebruiker..", "Even geduld", true,
            false);
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void run() {
    // add downloading code here
    HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader();
    String url = "*****";
    url += Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();

    gebruiker = jsonHelper.getGebruiker((httpReader.getTextFromUrl(url)
            .trim()));

    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (gebruiker == null) {
            // ga naar aanmaken gebruiker
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    AanmakenUser.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            // ga naar hoofdmenu
            db.droppen();
            db.insertGebruiker(gebruiker);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Hoofdmenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // ga naar menu
        }
    }
};

public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**LogCat**

```
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at db.jochen.quizapp.MainActivity.run(MainActivity.java:68)
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
01-10 16:12:16.444: E/AndroidRuntime(6090):     ... 2 more
01-10 16:12:16.454: D/dalvikvm(6090): GC_CONCURRENT freed 79K, 48% free 2843K/5379K, external 3695K/4614K, paused 2ms+5ms
01-10 16:12:16.454: W/ActivityManager(278):   Force finishing activity db.jochen.quizapp/.MainActivity
01-10 16:12:16.544: E/SkLayout_wtle(6090): ellipsis failed line number does not match 1 0
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: finish the match exclude list procedure, but can not match any one
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: GoDormant? 0
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: Threads Status Mutex Locked in fdm_main_loop
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: Threads Status Mutex Unlocked in fdm_main_loop
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: finish the match exclude list procedure, but can not match any one
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: GoDormant? 0
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: Threads Status Mutex Locked in fdm_main_loop
01-10 16:12:16.624: D/fast-dormancy(165): [FDM]: Threads Status Mutex Unlocked in fdm_main_loop
01-10 16:12:16.624: I/ActivityManager(278): No longer want com.sonyericsson.tvlauncher (pid 4961): hidden #16
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090): Activity db.jochen.quizapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afd4aa0 that was originally added here
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity db.jochen.quizapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2afd4aa0 that was originally added here
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:269)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:109)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:97)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at db.jochen.quizapp.MainActivity.downloadData(MainActivity.java:59)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at db.jochen.quizapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
01-10 16:12:16.664: E/WindowManager(6090):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: **Off-topic**- you can filter your logcat by error so you get only the necessary logs.

Comment: Yeah I know but I didn't make the log myself. My device doens't throw the exception and works just fine but thanks anyway!

Comment: What is line 68 of `MainActivity`?

Comment: Line 68 is HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can you manage the request sent to a handler if your thread is not listening on a looper?

Doc says:
public Handler ()

Added in API level 1
Default constructor associates this handler with the Looper for the current thread. If this thread does not have a looper, this handler won't be able to receive messages so an exception is thrown.

If you want a secondary thread to be able to manage a Handler you must call Looper.prepare()

Example:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private Handler mHandler;

    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    // manage the message
                }
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void stopLooper() {
        if (Looper.myLooper()!=null)
            Looper.myLooper().quitSafely();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should i call this looper? In public void run()?

Comment: Added example to the answer

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! Do you have any idea why it was working on some devices?

Comment: Probably because your thread was still alive when receiving a message on the handler. The looper ensures your thread to be alive, until you stop itself (calling quit() on the looper).
Then the example should be modified in order to be able to access the looper from the external.

Answer (score 1):

You handler may be created in another thread, not main which does not have looper. To avoid this you should create handler in thread with looper (ex: in main thread, in onCreate), or provide looper to a handler:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to perform action in the background is really odd (i.e. `Activity implements Runnable`). I guess, the problem lays in the way you call `downloadData()` method, perhaps, from other background threads. (By the way, how do you call it, i.e. where do you store the reference to the MainActivity?)

Your task is easily solved by [`Loaders`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), which perfectly match Activity's lifecycle and requires much less code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'm only a beginner at Android development :) The MainActivity is started by starting the app, if that is what you mean.

Comment: No, I mean, that if `downloadData()` method is public, then you have to somehow hold a reference to the MainActivity instance in order to call it. And this is very bad practice, since it likely causes memory leaks.